# Amazon ACM `CertificateNotFound` with imported certificate. `describe-certificate` works fine

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, amazon-elb

I've imported my certificate into Amazon ACM:

```sh
aws --region us-west-2 acm import-certificate \
  --certificate file://my_cert.crt \
  --certificate-chain file://vendor_ca.crt \
  --private-key file://private_key.key
```

This gives me a Certificate ARN. I can see all the details with the describe-certificate command:

```sh
aws --region us-west-2 acm describe-certificate --certificate-arn "<my-certificate-arn>"
```

When I try to add the certificate to an ELBv2, I get a `CertificateNotFound` error.

```sh
aws --region=us-west-2 elbv2 add-listener-certificates \
  --listener-arn "<my-listener-arn>" \
  --certificates "CertificateArn=<my-certificate-arn>"

An error occurred (CertificateNotFound) when calling the AddListenerCertificates operation: Certificate '<my-certificate-arn>' not found
```

(I've redacted the arn id for this post, but it really is copy/paste identical)

The Certificate is clearly there. Obviously, something is wrong. I have other certificates that work without this error. Is there any way I can troubleshoot this further and find what the problem is?

Comment: Is the imported certificate 4096-bit? If so you can't use with ELB https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/create-https-listener.html#https-listener-certificates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @JonoCoetzee suggested my issue was the certificate was 4096-bit and ELB doesn't work with those and gives a slightly misleading error message.